# How to spawn a new xterm with the same environment

Tags: linux, shell, virtualenv

I'm using `virtualenv` (which sets some environment variables). Now, I want to spawn a new terminal window that have the same environment. If I try:

```
xterm &
```

I get a new terminal but the environment is the default environment, that is when I enter the following line on the new terminal:

```
pserve --reload development.ini
```

I get:

```
>> pserve: Command not found.
```

On the other hand, if I execute:

```
xterm -e pserve --reload development.ini &
```

It opens a new terminal that runs pserve. So, my questions are:

1. How to generally open a new terminal with the same environment
2. How can the new terminal find `pserve` when I run it with `-e` switch?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on superuser?

Comment: @m4tx - I too wasn't sure - as this is very relevant to `virtualenv` and development of web-apps with `Pyramids` and `Python` - You are welcome to flag - maybe mods will decide to move it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, a quick and dirty way of doing it is to use the sh builtin 'set' command (more see 'help set').

From the old shell:

```
set > ~/env.tmp
```

Then

```
xterm &
```

From the new shell:

```
. ~/env.tmp && rm ~/env.tmp
```

You may want to wrap this up in a script or add a couple of functions in your 'bash.rc'.  You may also want to use 'mktemp(1)' or similar.

Comment: This probably works if you have administrative rights on the machine, which I don't... `. ~/env.tmp && rm ~/env.tmp` gives me `Permission denied`

Comment: I've tested this locally with a restricted user and works fine.  Can you expand out the paths, or use /tmp for the .tmp file?

Comment: I think that `.` is giving me the `Permission denied.` - I'm using some kind of Debian distro `3.0.3-aufs-mos-2`. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Can you make up a simple environment (discard anything you have) and re-run these commands?  Also try to use 'source ~/env.tmp && rm ~/env.tmp' too.

Comment: `source` gives bunch of errors as it tries to execute the file - `HOST: Command not found. OS: Command not found.` etc.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/csh` if that what you mean

Comment: I am not experienced with csh, I've tested this with sh.  It should work with sh.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice from @dmp I added to my ~/.bashrc the following:

```
# save the environment, apart from readonly variables that can not be restored
alias cloneterm='set |egrep -v "^(BASHOPTS|BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID)=" > /tmp/env.tmp && $TERM &'
# restore a previously saved environment, if any
[ -f /tmp/env.tmp ] && source /tmp/env.tmp
[ -f /tmp/env.tmp ] && rm /tmp/env.tmp
```

Now I can simply run

```
$ cloneterm
```

and I get a new terminal window, with the same environment

Hope this helps

Notes:

- this is bash-only but should work tith other terminals too (even f I only tested it on xterm)
- this may break in multi-user systems, but is more than enough for desktop/laptop configurations